# How to have a cell above another

Tags: html, cell, overlap

Is it possible to marge two cells and to keep the text, in order to have a text above another?

```html
 <tr>           
   <td colspan="1" style="font-family: 'Chivo', sans-serif;;
       font-size: 300px;
       font-weight: 900;
       letter-spacing: 6px;
       padding-left: 20px;">
       30 
                        
   </td>
   <td style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
       font-size: 20px;
       font-weight: 900;">
       %
   </td>
   <td style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
       font-size: 30px;
       font-weight: 900;
       letter-spacing: 4px;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       padding-top: 20px">
       FF
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [CSS Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp):

```css
.number {
  font-size:80px;
}

.percent {
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
}

.letter {
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<table><tr>
    <td class="number">30</td>
    <td class="percent">%</td>
    <td class="letter">FF</td>
</tr></table>
```